When to use ExecutorService-based vs. VirtualThread-based boundedElastic in Reactor?
I'm currently working on a project where I need to handle blocking network I/O operations efficiently without tying up essential system resources. I'm using Project Reactor and specifically the Schedulers.boundedElastic() scheduler. I understand that starting from version 3.6.0, boundedElastic() offers two different implementations based on the setup:

ExecutorService-based (PlatformThread)
Thread-per-task-based (VirtualThread)

Given these options, I'm unclear about when to choose the ExecutorService-based implementation (Platform Thread) versus the VirtualThread-based implementation. Considering that VirtualThreads are lightweight and consume fewer resources, they seem to offer better scalability and so I wonder if this should be the default choice starting with Java 21.
Could someone clarify the scenarios or considerations for choosing one implementation over the other? In which scenarios would one implementation be preferred over the other? Is it advisable to default to using VirtualThreads in a Java 21+ environment?

Usually, Java goes to great lengths to keep the existing behavior of APIs consistent from one version of Java to the next.  That’s probably why existing APIs which did not use virtual threads before, don’t use them now.  As for whether to use virtual threads now… you probably should, unless you’re managing your own thread pool somehow.

I guess it depends on the IO layer design. If it's designed for Virtual Threads - go for it. Otherwise the standard threads would be same or maybe more efficient.

Virtual Threads are not for everything and there are a couple of pitfalls.
https://quarkus.io/blog/virtual-thread-1/#five-things-you-need-to-know-before-using-virtual-threads-for-everything)
